# Is the phrase 'lock a target on sth' correct?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, expressions

Let's assume a sniper wants to say 'I am aiming at the objective and I have my crosshairs right on it'. I've always thought they would use an expression 'I locked on/onto the target'.

However, recently, I encountered a sentence: 'His heart isn't something anyone can just lock their target on' (nevermind that said 'lock-on' is used here figuratively).

It seems that an author, instead of 'to lock on sth', used a phrase 'to lock a target on sth', as if the 'target' was, I reckon, the crosshairs itself, not the desired objective. Therefore, my question is whether 'lock a target on sth' is correct or maybe it is just a mistake of a non-native speaker.

Comment: It's confusing.  Probably a backwards reference to "the target is locked on", or some such.  I would avoid the usage.

Comment: And target locking isn't a sniper thing. It's guidance system or target designator system thing. It's used figuratively in conventional arms. It was first applied to radar guided gun batteries on ships. Battery elevation and traverse was slaved to the search radar via a computer. So no—a sniper wouldn't say that.

Comment: I am not familiar with the military, plus, there's only one word in my language meaning "to target" in terms of both a radar and a shooter, hence the inaccuracy. What is then another way for a sniper to say 'The target's right in the reticle'? Would 'I homed in on the target' or 'target acquired' be correct?